# Getting AttributeError while using tf.keras.layers.LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

When i am using tf.keras.layers.LSTM (Trying to use GPU instance) i am getting below error , while normal keras.layers.LSTM works fine(Not using GPU)

Model which i am using for creating the model , if i use keras.layers.LSTM works fine.

```
def build_model(embedding_matrix, num_aux_targets):
    title = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
    question_body = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
    answer = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
    #category = Input(shape=(1,))

    title_embb = Embedding(*embedding_matrix.shape, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False )(title)
    question_body_embb = Embedding(*embedding_matrix.shape, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(question_body)
    answer_embb = Embedding(*embedding_matrix.shape, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(answer)
    concat = Concatenate(axis=1)
    embb_final = concat([title_embb,question_body_embb,answer_embb])

    x1 = SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(embb_final)
    x1 = Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM_UNITS, return_sequences=True))(x1)
    hidden1 = concatenate([
        GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x1), 
        GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x1),#layer returns a fixed-length output vector for each example by averaging over the sequence dimension. This allows the model to handle input 
        #of variable length in the simplest way possible.
    ])
    hidden1 = add([hidden1, Dense(DENSE_HIDDEN_UNITS, activation='relu')(hidden1)])

    result = Dense(30, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
    model = Model(inputs=[title,question_body,answer], outputs= result)
    model._name = 'mymodel'
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return model
```

After calling the model , i am getting below error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   2238       try:
-> 2239         super(tracking.AutoTrackable, self).__setattr__(name, value)
   2240       except AttributeError:

AttributeError: can't set attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-8baf6fbe617d> in <module>
      1 for model_idx in range(NUM_MODELS):
----> 2     model = build_model(embedding_matrix,1)
      3     for global_epoch in range(EPOCHS):
      4 
      5         model.fit(

<ipython-input-61-925b81ce0745> in build_model(embedding_matrix, num_aux_targets)
     12 
     13     x1 = SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(embb_final)
---> 14     x1 = Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM_UNITS, return_sequences=True,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',recurrent_dropout=0,unroll=False,use_bias=True))(x1)
     15     hidden1 = concatenate([
     16         GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x1),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in __init__(self, layer, merge_mode, weights, **kwargs)
    366                              'Merge mode should be one of '
    367                              '{"sum", "mul", "ave", "concat", None}')
--> 368         self._set_sublayers(layer)
    369         self.merge_mode = merge_mode
    370         if weights:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     28         prev_value = _DISABLE_TRACKING.value
     29         _DISABLE_TRACKING.value = True
---> 30         out = func(*args, **kwargs)
     31         _DISABLE_TRACKING.value = prev_value
     32         return out

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in _set_sublayers(self, layer)
    390         config['go_backwards'] = not config['go_backwards']
    391         self.backward_layer = layer.__class__.from_config(config)
--> 392         self.forward_layer.name = 'forward_' + self.forward_layer.name
    393         self.backward_layer.name = 'backward_' + self.backward_layer.name
    394 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   2242             ('Can\'t set the attribute "{}", likely because it conflicts with '
   2243              'an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a '
-> 2244              'different name.').format(name))
   2245       return
   2246 

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "name", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

I am not using any attribute "name" in the code and also not allowed to upgrade or downgrade Keras or TF versions.

Comment: Please post your [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Also which version of TF and Keras you are using?

Comment: Tensorflow Version Version: 2.1.0rc0 and Keras version 2.3.1

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: @buntyshah Avoid using ```model._name = 'mymodel'``` in you model description

Comment: i removed that still its he same error , i actually added this once i started receiving the error.